# Почему в конце .json файла добавляются лишние скобки?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./point.json', 'utf8'));
var prefix = "!";
let userData = points[message.author.id];
  if(command === "buyLevel") {
if(userData.points >= 100){
  userData.points -= 100;
  userData.level++;
  message.reply(`ты получил новый уровень, у тебя осталось ${userData.points} монет-а.`);


  fs.writeFile("./point.json", JSON.stringify(points), (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err)
  });
}
else {
  message.reply("У тебя не достаточно так называемых денежных средств");
}
```

после добавления уровня в конец .json добавляются 1-2 скобки }}
как сделать так чтобы этого не происходило ?
json выглядит так:

```
{"198892931224961024":{"points":4,"level":10},"256434786875211778":{"points":44,"level":1}}
```

Comment: Почему вы считаете что они лишние? Покажите, как оно должно быть по вашему?

Comment: @vp_arth подозреваю, что ТС собирается дописывать туда данные

Comment: Потому что консоль выдаёт ошибку{"points":12,"level":0},"287259453060022273":{"points":16,"level":0}}}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 362

Comment: JSON-строка, которая в вопросе, - правильная, за исключением пропущенного двоеточия.

Comment: @igor, так она выглядит до добавления уровня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходило из-за Nodemon.